# Problem when inserting text from a function in a for loop

Tags: vimscript, insert-mode

I have a function that animates the insertion of the contents of the last modified register at the cursor's location as if someone was typing it:

```
function! AnimateInsertion() abort
    " split contents of last modified reg in individual chars
    let s:line = split(getreg(v:register), '\zs')
    " iterate through each character
    for s:char in s:line
        sleep 100m
        exe 'normal!a' s:char
        redraw
    endfor
endfunction
```

When I run this function with the text `Try me` inside the last modified register, the following text gets inserted:

```
 T r y   m e
```

Evidently, there is a problem with the `exe 'normal!a' s:char` line. Why are the spaces between the letter being inserted? What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, arguments to `:execute` are separated with a space. `:execute '123' '456'` is the same as `:execute '123 456'`.

To avoid the space, use `.`:

```
execute 'normal! a'.s:char
```